# Twitter - Request user tweets with API key

Tags: json, api, twitter, key

I use PHP and maybe jQuery (Javascript) to get the latest tweet from a user. I tried to get Twitter data with JSON earlier but when the data is requested too many times and Twitter says no.

They want us to use an API key to accept access to get the data. I have read about it but can't figure out how it works.

What I think I need is a JSON string that contains the KEY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way was to do it without a key anyway. The API key is more important if posting stuff to Twitter.